# why this resolves to undefined not window/global-env in react component method if it not bind this in constructor

Tags: reactjs, this, undefined

Just described as title.

I got answers that how to fix the situation - `this` refers to `undefined`.

But no answer tells me why `this` refers to `undefined`.

In my opinion, `this` will refer to `window/global-env` if it isn't specified implicitly or explicitly.

Of course ,`this` will be `undefined` when in `strict-mode`.

Comment: *Of course ,this will be undefined when in strict-mode* - if you understand the reason, why the question?

Comment: 3Q,  this is a stupid question. The way I verified method in strict mode or not is wrong before. I do verified again, found method is in strict mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use code below to verify method is in strict mode or not.

Include code below in method.

Got a type error, that means , method is in strict mode, which resolve the confusion.

```js
var obj2 = { get x() { return 17; } };
obj2.x = 5;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is determined at runtime and depending on the code, it can be something different.

*this is*

- determined at runtime, when a function is envoked
- determined by how a function is invoked, not where the function is
  defined
- a reference to an  object.
- will always be an object
- global (this) not available in strict mode

Example 1: *this* = `window`

```js
var name = 'Global';

var callName1 = function() {
  var name = 'Peter';
  console.log('--- From callName1 ----');
  console.log(this.name);
  //console.log(this);
  callName2();
}


var callName2 = function() {
  var name = 'Jane';
  console.log('--- From callName2 ----');
  console.log(this.name);
  //console.log(this);
}

callName1();

var execute = function(fn) {
  var name = 'Mary';
  console.log('--- From execute ----');
  console.log(this.name);
  //console.log(this);
}

execute(callName2);
```

Example 2: not available in strict mode

```js
'use strict';

var name = 'Global';

var callName1 = function() {
  var name = 'Peter';
  console.log('--- From callName1 ----');
  console.log(this.name);
  console.log(this);
}

callName1();
```

Example 3: examining *this* with method invocation

```js
var name = 'global';

var obj = {
  name: 'James Obj1',
  func: function() {
    console.log('--- From func ----');
    console.log(this.name);
    console.log(this); // this reference obj1
  }
}

obj.func()

var obj2 = {
  name: 'Jame Obj2',
  func: obj.func // this reference obj2, but the function is defined in obj1
}

obj2.func()

var obj3 = {
  name: 'Kane Obj3',
  obj4: {
    name: 'Mary Obj4',
    func: function () {
      console.log('--- From obj4 ----');
      console.log(this.name);
      console.log(this); // this reference obj4
    }
  }
}
obj3.obj4.func()
```

With `() => {}` function *this* - is lexically bound. It means that it uses `this` from the code that contains the arrow function.

Comment: was there problem with answer or did I miss something?